# How can I use induction to prove the Triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, induction

By using induction, I want to prove the following:

$||x_{1} + ... +  x_{k}||  \leqq  ||x_{1}|| + ... + ||x_{k}||$

with $(x_{1}, ... , x_{k}) \in R^{n}$

I started with:

$||x_{1} + ... +  x_{k} + x_{k+1}||  \leqq  ||x_{1}|| + ... + ||x_{k}|| + ||x_{k+1}||$

But, I'm not sure how to proceed, as I don't know how I should manipulate the terms inside the determinant symbols.

Comment: Are you trying to show this using the assumption that $\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$? Because if you don't know that, that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice The base case just states that $||x_1+x_2 || \leq ||x_1|| + ||x_2||$. Assume

$$ || x_1 + ... + x_n || \leq ||x_1|| + ... + ||x_n|| $$

We want to show that same when $n+1$. But,

$$ || x_1 + ... + x_n + x_{n+1} || = || (x_1 + ... + x_n) + x_{n+1} ||$$

Now apply the base case to the elements $X = x_1 + ... + x_n$ and $Y = x_{n+1}$. So we have

$$ || X + Y || \leq || X|| + ||Y|| $$

hence,

$$ || x_1 + ... + x_n + x_{n+1} || \leq ||x_1 + ... + x_n|| + ||x_{n+1}|| $$

Using the induction hypothesis, one has

$$ || x_1 + ... + x_n + x_{n+1} || \leq ||x_1 + ... + x_n|| + ||x_{n+1}||  \leq ||x_1|| + ... + ||x_n|| + || x_{n+1} || $$

and the result is proved.

Comment: Arguably, the base case asserts $\|x_1\| \le \|x_1\|$.

Comment: @TheoBendit The base case is really both together, but only one half of it is needed in the inductive step. Oh wait, maybe the case with $0$ addends needs to be included too...

Comment: @J.G. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @TheoBendit This is an example of an inductive argument in which the base case covers multiple $n$.